# What is the formula for fans per day in Join Avenue?

Tags: pokemon-black-2-white-2

In pokemon Black 2 and White 2, in Join avenue, everyone seems sure you get more fans as time goes on, based on... something. Game progression? Popularity in Pokemon Studio? Join Avenue Rank?

What are all the factors that contribute? I'd like to know how many NPCs I'm getting each day so I don't sit here waiting when I've reached the maximum for my game progression.

ETA: I no longer remember exactly how many I was getting a day, but it was far shy of 12, and I did not have a large number of streetpasses or anything like that. This makes me believe that you only get 12 when you reach some milestone, and you get a slowly increasing number before then.

Comment: Though I don't know exacts, it's been my experience that rank affects it. But not each rank up... It was like 5 before I started seeing any real improvement in fans. But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The total maximum is 20, up to 12 of which can come from the game itself, while up to 8 can come from encounters with other real players. This information has limited availability, I've only found it on the German wiki project [PokeWiki](http://www.pokewiki.de/Einklangspassage). Other sources neither confirm nor neglect this fact. The exact formula or waypoints for the increase of ingame fans is unknown as far as i can tell, but the only relevant factors are Avenue level and game progress (which can only be reliably tracked with the number of badges including beating the elite four, so there should be a maximum of 9 waypoints for game progress, probably less).
***Edit:*** according to [supercheats](http://www.supercheats.com/pokemon-white-2/walkthrough/join-avenue), you take over all your pokestar fans into join avenue. So this should be an additional way to get a number.

While you can get [NPCs](http://www.serebii.net/black2white2/joinavenue.shtml) into your Join Avenue by using C-Gear Connection Features such as the GTS or Infrared, those are tied to the players you connect to.

The fans that appear just like that and populate your avenue without you having to connect to anyone are drawn randomly from a limited pool of characters.
The only thing that affects which ones appear is whether or not you have beaten the Elite Four. Even then, I think they can still appear, but won't open a shop. Serebii has a [list](http://www.serebii.net/black2white2/joinavenuefans.shtml) of all of them.

Comment: I'm consistently getting the same number of fans per day, though, which leads me to believe that the NUMBER of fans follows a formula, even if the specific fans are random.

Comment: Have you allowed any of them to open shops? If you have and your shops are maxed out, has their number changed since you maxed out the number of shops?

Comment: I have opened shops. I have to go boot up the game again to remember if I maxed out the slots yet,  but if not I'm close to it. I don't remember what the number of guests was, but I was getting the same number every day, plus the one person I streetpassed (until I had him open a shop as well).

Comment: Well, the total maximum is 12 and StreetPass people are separate with a maximum of 8.

Comment: I didn't have 12, it was like, 2 or 3, but I haven't maxed out my Join Avenue rank

Answer (score 3):

Quoted from [bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Join_Avenue), emphasis mine:

> A set amount of strolling NPCs, known as the player's fans (Japanese: ファン fan), will arrive at the avenue each day. **This amount is determined by the avenue's rank and the player's game progression.** After the player has entered the Hall of Fame, Gym Leaders will occasionally arrive among these, as a bonus.

Immediately later in the same paragraph:

> The avenue can hold **no more than twelve visiting NPC fans at a time.** Consequently, no NPC fans will arrive on a day on which this limit has already been reached, even if the player subsequently makes room. This also means that any amount of arriving NPC fans that would have otherwise exceeded the limit will be capped.

The above explains why you have as much as 12 fans.

I don't know the exact formula that determines how the number of fans should be each day, but it seems to be related to your avenue rank, the number of badges you have, and main story checkpoints.

The NPC fans between themselves otherwise seem to be unlocked randomly, meaning that you probably don't need to reach a certain point for unlocking this or that NPC (besides those unlocked by entering the Hall of Fame for the first time).

I also found this on [pokemongts](http://www.pokemongts.com/pokepedia.php?action=view&aid=128):

> To get fans to come to Join Avenue, the player needs to become "popular" by the game's standards. This means becoming famous via Pokestar Studios, doing Pokemon Musicals, and doing well in the Pokemon World Tournament and Battle Subway.

Unfortunately, I cannot exactly confirm this, but at least, now you know when you can stop waiting so you don't "sit here waiting" when you've progressed in-game.

---

If you want to get fans that are not in-game generated, you still have a maximum of 12 fans per day (This also means that you if you have 12 fans who visit due to player interactions, you won't be receiving in-game fans on that day).

For instance, there is this method named [Magnemite Coil](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/661226-pokemon-black-version-2/64347250) which was used by players at the time the game was still widely popular so that they could develop their Join Avenue as fast as possible (thus ignoring the game progression part for in-game fans).

Comment: That's basically what prompted me to ask the question. What's it based on, how many fans per day based on what milestones, et cetera. Is it X fans per badge, or X fans per studio fame, or what?

Comment: Besides the information already in the question and in my answer, this basically adds a link and a quote. Does that really warrant an own answer? Additionally, where does the info about the maximum of 12 fans come from? It's not explicitly stated in any of the sources you quote and i have found a source that does explicitly state otherwise (editing it into my answer).

Comment: @scenia Bulbapedia did say that, as does pokemongts and the gamefaqs thread. As for the content, I felt that it did warrant an own answer. Answers don't need to only add to previous answers; they can contain everything from the start to be complete on their own.

Comment: Bulbapedia says there can't be more than 12 *fans*. It says nothing about *other players*. Pokemongts cites Serebii and bulbapedia as sources (and own research, which is limited to gym leader recommendations), which means the author could have interpreted that information wrong as well. With all the online resources available and a rather active community, i don't see how the wiki i linked would keep information so substantially wrong (if it were wrong). I'm not saying this has to be true, but there is a strong point towards it.

Comment: @scenia I guess we disagree on that then. "At its peak, participants in the Coil can reach their max of 12 visitors in a short period of time by just waiting for their offer to be fulfilled" - pokemongts. "you can only have a max of 12 pending visitors in your Join Avenue at a time" - gamefaqs. And while a wiki can be accurate, it can also be inaccurate.

Comment: That's true. I can't try myself, don't have a black/White 2 with me right now...